# Laravel Eloquent ORM - save() returns column not found (MySQL error)

Tags: php, orm, model, laravel-4, eloquent

The issue I'm running into is that I want to save the model, but I have a method call which writes to the instance and for some reason Laravel is trying to update *that* column.

Club Model (relevant code):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Club extends Eloquent 
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $table = 'clubs';
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'contact_name', 'contact_email', 'contact_phone', 'contact_photo', 'club_code', 'logo');


    public function getCurrentCampaign($id = 0)
    {

        if (!$id)
        {
            if ($this->currentCampaign)
            {
                return $this->currentCampaign;
            }

            $id = $this->id;
        }

        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->currentCampaign = DB::table('campaigns')
            ->where('club_id', $id)
            ->where('start_date', '<=', $now)
            ->where('end_date', '>=', $now)
            ->pluck('id');

        return $this->currentCampaign;
    } 
}
```

The issue exists on the "club settings" page where a user can edit some stuff - I have a few updates that run on different tables, and then later I use `$club->save()`. I found that even if I call it directly after `getCurrentCampaign`, it throws the error.

```
    $club = Club::findOrFail($clubID);
    $club->getCurrentCampaign();
    $club->save(); // Error
```

Error message:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'currentCampaign' in 'field list' (SQL: update`clubs`set`updated_at`= 2014-07-08 12:49:17,`currentCampaign`= 27 where`id`= 23)`

Considering that `currentCampaign` isn't in the `$fillable` array, I don't know what's happening. Am I misunderstanding how that works?

Thanks

Edit: For clarity, there are a few different things loaded into `$club`, not just the campaigns. I'm simply giving one for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Anything that you save on the Model object that is NOT a property would be treated as an attribute/table column. To avoid this you can simply declare those properties on the model:

```
// Club model
public $currentCampaign;
```

Then using your code won't cause the error you experience now.

Anyway, probably you should consider @watcher's suggestion on working with relations instead, but that depends on your app.

---

And about the `fillable` array - it has nothing to do with saving data but rather with filling object with an array of data (mass assignement):

```
$model->fill($someArray);
```

this is called when you `__construct` new object, save or update providing an array etc.

Comment: Gotcha. That kinda sucks; I like the way it worked in my head better, haha.

Comment: This is because when a property is not defined in a class, it is not accessible, so PHP calls the `__set()` method, which Eloquent defines to put that property into the list of table columns.

I had the same problem with a `private` property defined in a trait which was used by a model, which, in turn, I have subclassed. My class has no access to the property because it's private and not visible from the subclasses, so that property was misinterpreted as a table column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're specifying your campaign relationship in 'the laravel way'.  The underlying issue is that you're adding a property to your model, and, during saving, Eloquent believes that extra non-standard property represents a column in your database so it is trying to save it as such.

This is the path I'd take to solve it:

```
public function campaigns()
{
    // 'hasMany' may not be what you need, just guessing 
    // from what I see so far... 
    return $this->hasMany('Campaigns');
}

public function currentCampaigns($now)
{
    return $this->campaigns
        ->where('start_date', '>', $now)
        ->where('end_date', '<', $now);
}
```

Now, given an instance of a 'club', you can get its current campaigns like this:

```
$club->currentCampaigns(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

The relationship above is determined by how you structure the relationship in the database.

1. If your club table has a 'campaign_id' field, then the relationship in the club model to the campaign model would be `belongsTo`.
2. If there is a third table that has both campaign ids and club ids in it and thats how you determine what clubs are related to what campaigns, that relationship is `hasMany`

I belive also if you have a `campaign_id` in your clubs table, it will need to be present in the fillable array in order to actually be able to set it.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it's a little too far into the project to actually refactor that much :( Also, it's not just the campaigns that have an issue, though - there's a few more things that get loaded into the `$club` variable which also cause errors. That was just the easiest to explain.

Comment: I think your ultimate issues is you need to stay away from defining properties on your models on the fly like that.  Eloquent believes those to be columns.

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Thanks!